# How to use onClick and a href in same sentence?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the following code for a menu sliding bar. But when I click a href I want to go on page and get ".gs-hamburger" function to sliding up the menu bar after it is going to page.

```
<nav class="gs-nav-right" id="gs-nav-right">
              <i class="icon-menu55 gs-hamburger" id="gs-close-nav-right"></i>
              <div class="gs-nav-right-content">
                <ul class='text-center'>
                <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/choose">Choose your Image</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/vote" onClick="GSnavRight();">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
        </nav>

  <!-- ========================================================================= -->

    <script src="vendors/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    'use-strict';

    var $window = $(window);
    var GSnavRight = function(){
        $('.gs-hamburger').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.gs-hamburger').toggleClass('gs-close');
            $('#gs-nav-static-hamburger').toggleClass('gs-nav-right-appear');
            $('main,#gs-navfix,#gs-nav-static').toggleClass('gs-nav-right-appear');
            $('#gs-nav-right').toggleClass('gs-appear');
        });

    };

    GSnavRight();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Weird style to write HTML & JavaScript. Can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pj5s6ho5/1/ this is but I can't run a bootstramp.css file as external resources

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because you want to make one edit on current page and change of page. If you change of page, you can't keep the edits that Jquery made on previous page on next page. Iy fou only want to use front "tools", you need to use cookies or localstorage(only for real browsers, not for old IE). If you have access to backend, you can use session or other things (depending on the tehcnology you are using)

in Pure html, you can also use iframes but it is really not recommended, or you can use anchor links but  I expect that your html architecture will change a lot.